# Calculating gaussian curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

I am stuck with this problem. The quadric surface $xy=z^2+z$ is given to me, and I have to find the gaussian curvature in $(0,0,0)$. Is there an easy way? I have tried parametrizing it but I was unable to do that.

Can I go to the projective space, and choose $z+w=0$ as the plan at infinity? Doing that I can find an easy parametrization, but I am not sure the gaussian curvature remains the same.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered the formulas given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature#Alternative_formulas)?

Comment: Can you solve (say, using implicit differentiation) for the second-order partial derivatives of $z=f(x,y)$ at the origin? (Or, even easier, in this case you could find $f(x,y)$ explicitly, just using the quadratic formula.)